# If a boolean returns true, store in array

Tags: bash, syntax

I want to store all the elements of another array that meet the true criteria in an array. (`LOCALES` is an array of locations in the server.)

```
for loc in "${LOCALES[@]}"; do
    if sudo [ -d $loc/bin/ ]; then
        # some command that will store it in an array
    fi
done
```

What would I want to enter to make sure all true commands are stored?

Comment: "Snippet" functionality is only for code that can run in a browser (it's StackOverflow's answer to JSFiddle), and implicitly sets your code to be syntax-highlighted as HTML. Use the `{}` button, or triple quotes, or four-space indents, for everything else.

Answer (score 4):

You can append to an array with `+=`, like this:

```
locales_present=() # initialize array
for loc in "${LOCALES[@]}"; do
  if sudo [ -d "$loc/bin" ]; then
    locales_present+=("$loc")
  fi
done
```

Remember to enclose `$loc` in double quotes in the sudo statement.

Comment: You get the UV for being soothsayer or mind-reader for discerning the intent of the question alone...